# как сделать параметр необязательным в disnake?

Tags: python

Есть вот такой кусок кода:

```py
@bot.slash_command()
async def role(inter, role: disnake.Role = commands.Param(description = "Роль"))
```

Хочу сделать, чтобы **role** стал необязательным параметром. Пробовал в commands.Param() внести required = False, но тогда в консоли вижу это:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 590, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/params.py", line 1169, in Param
    raise TypeError(f"Param() got unexpected keyword arguments: {a}")
TypeError: Param() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'required'

[Program finished]
```

Comment: ``role`` в этом коде уже является необязательным параметром.

Comment: нет, требует заполнение

Comment: что именно пишет?

Comment: ну так и пишет как обычно в слэш-командах "Этот вариант необходим. Укажите значение"

Comment: какой "этот"? Какой полный текст.

Comment: так и пишет. списал с дискорда без изменений

Comment: пишет на опцию role

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def role(inter, role: disnake.Role = None)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: как я помню это не алгебра и нельзя двойное равенство. типо role: disnake.Role = commands.Param() = None

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите документацию https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/api/app_commands.html#disnake.ext.commands.Param
Там есть параметр `default`, который как раз вам и нужен.

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def role(inter, role: disnake.Role = commands.Param(description = "Роль", default = None))
```